# How do you stop an AIR application?

Tags: air, aptana

At 1 minute into the "[See it in action](http://www.aptana.com/products/air/)" video, Paul stops the program from running.
What button did he push to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think he just pressed Command+Q on his keyboard to quit ADL (AIR Debug Launcher).  usually when you debug an AIR application, from Flash Authoring CS5 on Mac OS X, the top menu bar doesn't change.  you have to select another application, like Finder (by clicking the desktop) and then click on your AIR app to see the top menu bar reflect ADL.  i'm assuming the same thing happens when using Flash Builder and Aptana.